# Navigating to Page 2 on an event in Page 1 inside Frame WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a window called `CreateLot.xaml` which contains a frame as follows :

```
 <Frame Name="AddLotFrame" Content="{Binding Path=CurrentPage,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="Transparent"
               ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
               MinHeight="175" MinWidth="175" ></Frame>
```

In the viewmodel `CreateLotVm.cs` :

```
 public CreateLotVm()
        {
            AddLotPage addLot = new AddLotPage();
            AddLotPageVm vm = new AddLotPageVm(CurrentPage);
            addLot.DataContext = vm;
            CurrentPage = addLot; 
        }
```

Where I am binding `AddLotPage` to `CurrentPage` of frame.

Within `AddLotPage`, I have a form and a button. On the button press event I am doing some validations and database transaction. Now based on data entered in `AddLotPage` on button press event either Page 2, Page 3 or Page 4 should be displayed. In Other words AddLotFrame should Navigate to Page 2, Page 3 or Page 4 based on data entered in AddLotPage (Page 1).
So I want to update `CurrentPage` property of parent `AddLotFrame` from child `AddLotPage` page.
How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example inject `AddLotPage` or `AddLotPageVm` (depending on from where you want to navigate) with a reference to `CreateLotVm`:

**AddLotPageVm.cs:**

```
private readonly CreateLotVm _navigationVm;
public RelayCommand ButtonCommand;
public AddLotPageVm(CreateLotVm navigationVm)
{
    _navigationVm = navigationVm;
    ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(ButtonMethod);
}

public void ButtonMethod(object x)
{
    //...

    _navigationVm.CurrentPage = new Page2();
}
```

**CreateLotVm.cs:**

```
AddLotPage addLot = new AddLotPage(); 
AddLotPageVm vm = new AddLotPageVm(this);//<-- injection
addLot.DataContext = vm;
currentPage = addLot;
```

Comment: I did very similar thing  but using MVVM way. I used Command to execute `_navigationVm.CurrentPage = new Page2();` part in viewmodel AddLotVm.cs Thank you.

Comment: I definitely agree that you should inject the view model (AddLotPageVm) rather than the view if you follow the MVVM pattern.